# how to write scheme function that takes two lists and return one list like this

Tags: scheme, plai

how to implement this function

if get two list (a b c), (d e)

and return list (a+d b+d c+d a+e b+e c+e)

list element is all integer and result list's element order is free

I tried this like

```
(define (addlist L1 L2)
  (define l1 (length L1))
  (define l2 (length L2))
  (let ((result '()))
     (for ((i (in-range l1)))
        (for ((j (in-range l2)))
           (append result (list (+ (list-ref L1 i) (list-ref L2 j))))))))
```

but it return error because result is '()

I don't know how to solve this problem please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because functions like `append` don't mutate the containers. You could fix your problem with a mutating function like `append!`. Usually functions that mutate have a `!` in their name like `set!` etc.

But it's possible to achieve that without doing mutation. You'd have to change your algorithm to send the result to your next iteration. Like this:

```
(let loop ((result '()))
   (loop (append result '(1)))
```

As you can see, when loop will get called, result will be:

```
'()
'(1)
'(1 1)
'(1 1 1)
....
```

Following this logic you should be able to change your algorithm to use this method instead of `for` loop. You'll have to pass some more parameters to know when you have to exit and return `result`.

I'll try to add a more complete answer later today.

Here's an implementation of `append!` I just wrote:

```
(define (append! lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? (cdr lst1))
    (set-cdr! lst1 lst2)
    (append! (cdr lst1) lst2)))
```

Comment: thank you for answer!
but it returns "append! is unbound identifier"

I don't know why
should i implement something?

ah, my language is plai

Comment: Yeah `append!` isn't always present. I know there is also `list-append!` that does the same thing... check for the docs if it's available. If it doesn't exists you can implement it with `set-cdr!`.

Comment: if `null?` doesn't exists, you can use `(= (cdr lst1) '())` in theory.

Answer (score 2):

A data-transformational approach:

```
   (a b c ...) (x y ...) 
1.  ==>  ( ((a x) (b x) (c x) ...)  ((a y) (b y) (c y) ...) ...)
2.  ==>  (  (a x) (b x) (c x) ...    (a y) (b y) (c y) ...  ...)
3.  ==>  (  (a+x) (b+x) ... )

(define (addlist L1 L2)
    (map (lambda (r) (apply + r))    ; 3. sum the pairs up
         (reduce append '()          ; 2. concatenate the lists
            (map (lambda (e2)        ; 1. pair-up the elements
                    (map (lambda (e1) 
                            (list e1 e2))  ; combine two elements with `list`
                         L1))
                 L2))))
```

testing (in MIT-Scheme):

```
(addlist '(1 2 3) '(10 20))
;Value 23: (11 12 13 21 22 23)
```

Can you simplify this so there's no separate step #3?

---

We can further separate out the different bits and pieces in play here, as

```
(define (bind L f) (join (map f L)))
(define (join L) (reduce append '() L))
(define yield list)
```

then,

```
(bind '(1 2 3) (lambda (x) (bind '(10 20) (lambda (y) (yield (+ x y))))))
;Value 13: (11 21 12 22 13 23)

(bind '(10 20) (lambda (x) (bind '(1 2 3) (lambda (y) (yield (+ x y))))))
;Value 14: (11 12 13 21 22 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(define (addlist L1 L2)
  (for*/list ((i (in-list L1)) (j (in-list L2)))
    (+ i j)))

> (addlist '(1 2 3) '(10 20))
'(11 21 12 22 13 23)
```

The trick is to use `for/list` (or `for*/list` in case of nested `for`s) , which will automatically do the `append` for you. Also, note that you can just iterate over the lists, no need to work with indexes.

To get the result "the other way round", invert L1 and L2:

```
(define (addlist L1 L2)
  (for*/list ((i (in-list L2)) (j (in-list L1)))
    (+ i j)))

> (addlist '(1 2 3) '(10 20))
'(11 12 13 21 22 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

In scheme, it's not recommended using function like set! or append!.
because it cause data changed or Variable, not as Funcitonal Programming Style.

should like this:

```
(define (add-one-list val lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()
    (cons (list val (car lst)) (add-one-list val (cdr lst)))))

(define (add-list lst0 lst1)
  (if (null? lst0) '()
    (append (add-one-list (car lst0) lst1)
            (add-list (cdr lst0) lst1))))
```

first understanding function add-one-list, it recursively call itself, and every time build val and fist element of lst to a list, and CONS/accumulate it as final answer.

add-list function just like add-one-list.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (addlist L1 L2)
 (flatmap (lambda (x) (map (lambda (y) (+ x y)) L1)) L2))

(define (flatmap f L)
 (if (null? L)
     '()
     (append (f (car L)) (flatmap f (cdr L))))) 

1 ]=> (addlist '(1 2 3) '(10 20))

;Value 2: (11 12 13 21 22 23)
```

Going with Will and Procras on this one. If you're going to use scheme, might as well use idiomatic scheme.

Using for to build a list is a bit weird to me. (list comprehensions would fit better) For is usually used to induce sequential side effects. That and RSR5 does not define a for/list or for*/list.

Flatmap is a fairly common functional paradigm where you use append instead of cons to build a list to avoid nested and empty sublists

Comment: There's nothing weird about using `for` here, it is actually idiomatic Racket (what the OP is obviously using). Also, it's the only solution without `append`.